# How to calculate an hourly count (grouped by a timeStamp type) in Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

For a dataframe `df1` where `col1` is of type `DateType`, I do the following to get the **daily count**.

```
val df1_new=df1.groupBy("col1").count()
```

However, for my dataframe `df2` where `col2` is of type `TimestampType`, I want to get the count on a **per-hour basis**. But replicating the above code for this, results in separate count for every timestamp that differs by even a second.

What should I be doing to achieve the count on an hourly-basis for `df2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_trunc` to truncate the timestamps to the hour level:

```
val df2_new = df2.groupBy(date_trunc("hour", col("col2"))).count()
```